# how can we decide map region for our if we have multiple annotations throughout the map

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mkmapview

This code is working completely fine although when i have lots annotations from different different region, i am not able to set the region of the map so that i can see all annotation on the screen. Thats why some annotations are not visible.

How can we calculate my map region so that each and every annotations can we shown on the screen.

```
struct MapViewWithAnnotatios: UIViewRepresentable {
var viewModel: MapViewWithAnnotationsViewModel
// Location Manager object to request location updates from the core API
// Annotations array
var annotations: [MKPointAnnotation]?
var mapRegion:  MKCoordinateRegion
// @State var mapView: MKMapView?
var mapRegion1: MKCoordinateRegion?
// Setup function for the representable
func setup() {
    // Set other properties if needed
}

// Function to configure the representable view
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    // Call the setup function
    setup()
    // Initialize the representable view
    let mapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    }
     
    // Provide annotations if they exists
    if let annotations = annotations {
        mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
    }
    mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
    // Return the representable view
    if viewModel.isCircleOverlayNeeded {
        let miles = 3.0
        let meters = miles * 1609.34
        let circle = MKCircle(center: mapView.region.center, radius: meters)
        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(circle.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: .init(top: 20, left: 50, bottom: 20, right: 50) ,animated: true)
        mapView.addOverlay(circle)
    }
    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    print("updateUIView")
}
```

Comment: There isn't always a solution to this depending on the screen size and where the annotations are. There is a limit to how far the map can be zoomed out, and if the annotations require the map to be zoomed out further than that, there is no solution to this.

Comment: Also why are you not using SwiftUI's `Map`? It is available since iOS 14.

Comment: But currently i m just fixing it like this
 MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.selectedLocationLat, longitude: self.selectedLocationLng), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)) 

i want to increase span according to my map annotations lat and lon
can we?

Comment: From your array of annotations (lat,lon), you could pick the one with the smallest (lat,lon), then based on distance for example, pick the 
furthest one and create a MKCoordinateRegion from those two locations.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a solution in your code:

```
if let annotations = annotations {
    mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
}
```

That changes the visible region to show each annotation on the screen.

With the next line, you destroy your solution:

```
mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
```

a possible solution would be

```
if let annotations = annotations {
    mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
} else {
    mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
}
```